# Why does JMS' "createTextMessage" throw Exception with a string variable parameter but not on a litteral string?

Tags: java, jms

I'm currently creating a chat demo application using JMS, and when creating a message publisher I get a weird error. Here's the code I have:

```java
public class MessageEmission implements Runnable {

    private String queueName;
    private String message;

    public MessageEmission(String queueName, String message) {
        queueName = this.queueName;
        message = this.message;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Connection connection = CreateConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(message);
            Destination destination = session.createQueue(queueName);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
            producer.send(message);

            session.close();
            connection.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Caught: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Connection CreateConnection() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(Configuration.getActiveMqServerHost());
        Connection connection = null;

        try
        {
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Caught: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return connection;
    }
}
```

The error I get highlighted in VS Code is over here

```java
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(message);
```

The error is the following:

```
The method createTextMessage(String) in the type Session is not applicable for the arguments
```

Whenever I replace the parameter message by a litteral string like so, the error goes away.

```java
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("This is fine! :fire:");
```

If I use the message string variable as the parameter for the function, I get no compilation error, but the application crashes when I run it... I am not sure to understand what I am doing wrong, could someone explain me what's the issue?

In my main application class, I use the following to run the Runnable:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        thread(new MessageEmission("MESSAGE", "This"), false);
        thread(new MessageEmission("MESSAGE", "is"), false);
        thread(new MessageEmission("MESSAGE", "a"), false);
        thread(new MessageEmission("MESSAGE", "test"), false);
        thread(new MessageEmission("MESSAGE", "and"), false);
        thread(new MessageEmission("MESSAGE", "it"), false);
        thread(new MessageEmission("MESSAGE", "is"), false);
        thread(new MessageEmission("MESSAGE", "working"), false);
        thread(new MessageEmission("MESSAGE", "as"), false);
        thread(new MessageEmission("MESSAGE", "intended"), false);
        
        //SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    public static void thread(Runnable runnable, boolean daemon) {
        Thread brokerThread = new Thread(runnable);
        brokerThread.setDaemon(daemon);
        brokerThread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong assignment order in the constructor:

```
public MessageEmission(String queueName, String message) {
    this.queueName = queueName;   // assign the value of argument to field variable
    this.message = message;
}
```

Also you probably want to rename the `TextMessage` variable to avoid conflicts with the field `message`:

```
TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(message);  // here, message is equivalent to this.message
```

I also notice you use `Connection` and `Session` interfaces which both implement `AutoCloseable`, you can also use that object within a `try-with-resources` statement:

```
    // this ensures connection and session are closed at the end of the try block
    try (Connection connection = createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)) {
        
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(message);
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(queueName);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
        producer.send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Caught: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that you're creating a connection, session, producer, etc. for *every* message you send. This is a significant anti-pattern unless you're using something like a connection pool behind the scenes which is just returning the connection to the pool instead of physically closing the connection.